# Moving HP BL460c and partnered D2220sb blades to new c7000 slots

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, blade-server, blade-chassis

I need to move a Bl460c Gen9 Server Blade with its partnered D2220sb Storage Blade (with RHEL OS and Apps already installed) from slots/bays 1 and 2 from the lab C7000 chassis to ANOTHER C7000 chassis located in the live network into different slots/bays 13 and 14.

Assuming this can be done without any issues, what would be the correct procedure/order for shutting down and moving the blades to ensure that the existing configuration is not lost or corrupted:

Perform a graceful shutdown of the OS and poweroff of the blade server. (At this stage the Onboard Administrator shows the BL460c server blade as OFF (amber), but the D2220sb Storage Blade is still ON (green). Is there a way to poweroff the D2220sb?

1. Physically remove the D2220sb storage blade from bay 2 in the existing c7000 chassis
2. Physically remove the BL460c Gen9 server blade from bay 1 in the existing c7000 chassis
3. Physically install the D2220sb storage blade into bay 14 in the new c7000 chassis
4. Physically install the BL460c Gen9 server blade into bay 13 in the new c7000 chassis
5. The BL460c and D2220sb blades will be partnered and up and running.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what interconnects you have in either C7K but on the assumption they were passthroughs then;

Step 1. Shutdown the BL460c

Step 2. Move both blades at the same time

Step 3. Power on the BL460c
The end - there is nothing more to do.

Now you should really ensure the new slot has an iLO IP and it's OAs are on a compatible version for the blade's BIOS and iLO firmware but without knowing about your inters there's nothing more to be done.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Both the existing and destination c7000 chassis have 2x HP GbE2c Blade switches installed. Also the current OAs firmware version has been updated to 4.50 and this will also be updated on the destination c7000 chassis OAs prior to the blades being moved. The new slots (i.e. slot 13 for the blade server) will be configured with a new iLO IP once the blades are installed to allow Console access from the C7000 OA.

Comment: Ok, well in that case obviously you need to configure the new ports but otherwise you can just throw them over.

Comment: OK, thanks will let you know if I have any issues once implemented.

Comment: I can confirm that the procedure was executed yesterday without any issues. Thanks for the advice.